# Delta measure, calculate $\int_A f \space d \delta_p$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

We are looking at the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d),\delta_p)$, for all $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$:

$\delta_p(A):=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } p \in A \\
0, & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow   \overline {\mathbb {R}}$ arbitrary. Show that $f$ is measurable and calculate $\int_A f \space d \delta_p$.

This is probably not that difficult but I don't know how to do it. :(

Answer (score 0):

$\delta_p$ puts all the mass into the point $p$, so the integral is

$$ \int_{A}fd\delta_p= \begin{cases} f(p) & \text{if}~ p\in A\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}. $$

Comment: How do you show this rigorously?

Comment: A straight answer without any explanation is not very helpful...